# Cómo añadir una imagen a un ToolStripMenuItem generado automáticamente con MDIWindowListItem

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un proyecto en C# (Framework .NET) para escritorio (una aplicación de Windows con formularios). Tengo un formulario principal que es un MDIContainer, con una barra de menú y un ToolStripMenuItem llamado Ventanas que mostrará las ventanas abiertas dentro del MDIContainer. Esas ventanas que se abren dentro del MDIContainer tendrán siempre un icono predeterminado (típico icono en la esquina izquierda de la ventana). Mi problema es que los ToolStripMenuItem que se generan automáticamente cuando se abren dichas ventanas no contienen dicho icono a la izquierda como imagen; es decir, la propiedad Image del ToolStripMenuItem no tiene ninguna imagen.
Sé que hay varias formas de conseguir esto, pero ¿hay alguna forma automática que no he visto? ¿O se puede sobrescribir algún método?

Gracias.